# Let $x$ be a real number. If $x^3 + 7x^2 − 8 \leq 0$, then $x \leq 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, proof-verification, proof-writing

I was just wondering if this is a good way to write out this proof statement.  I used proof by contradiction.  I am pretty new at using this so I was just wondering if anyone on here could give me advice on the formatting of my proof.

**PROOF:** Suppose the opposite, $x^3+7x^2-8 \leq 0$ and $x>1$.
If $P$ and $\neg Q$ for all $x>1$, then it should be true for $x=2$.
Thus, $(2)^3 + 7(2)^2 - 8 \leq 0 \implies 8 + 28 - 8  \leq 0 \implies 28$ is not $\leq 0$.
Therefore, $P$ and $\neq Q$ is false. $\square$

Comment: Can't follow your argument.  What are $P$ and $-Q$?  Why  does the fact that there is some $x>1$ for which $f(x)≤0$ mean that we must have $f(2)≤0$?

Comment: Let P = x^3 + 7x^2 - 8 ≤ 0 and -Q = X >1

Comment: when $x \neq 1,$ what is $$ \frac{x^3 + 7 x^2 - 8}{x-1} \; ?  $$

Comment: Well, your logic is wrong.  To prove the desired theorem by contradiction you have to assume that there is some $x>1$ for which your polynomial is $≤0$ and derive a contradiction from that. You can not assume that this $x$ is $2$ or any other particular value.

Comment: We prove it by proving the contrapositive statement: $$x\gt 1\implies x^3+7x^2-8\gt 1^3+7\cdot 1^2-8=1+7-8=0$$ Note the **strict** inequality $\gt$ rather than $\geq$

Comment: Note that what Prasun just did requires you to prove that $x^3+7x^2-8$ is increasing on, say, $[0,\infty)$, but that's easy because all the nonconstant coefficients are positive.

Comment: I understand how this works but I am not allowed to use the contrapositive in this way for this one because I can't prove the polynomial is increasing on [0,infinity).    My professor wants us to use what we know from the class.  We haven't worked with increasing [0,infinity)  If that makes sense

Comment: @piza25, you should look at my answer, and fill in the details that are suggested, merely suggested, by the graph. For my part, I think students should still learn to sketch graphs on graph paper. Also: if you post a comment here without an at sign and the beginning of someone's user name, the system will not notify anyone that there is a comment waiting for them.   You can get pdf's of graph paper at https://www.printablepaper.net/category/graph   and then print out when needed.

Comment: @WillJagy thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, as a part of the *definition* of the $<$ sign and positive/negative numbers one has the following property:

> Given $a>0$ and $b>c$ it follows that $ab>ac$

In particular then, supposing $x>1$ one has

$x^2=x\cdot x> x\cdot 1=x$

Applying this once again, we have $x^3>x$ for all $x>1$

---

Suppose for the sake of proof by contrapositive that $x>1$

It follows then that $x^3>x>1$ and $7x^2>7x>7$ and therefore we have

$x^3+7x-8>1+7-8=0$

This proves then by contrapositive that $x^3+7x-8\leq 0$ implies $x\leq 1$

Answer (score 1):

Before guessing the correct language, you need to understand how the question relates to the graph. Since you can factor out the $x-1$ and get a quadratic, you can use the quadratic formula to find the other two roots.

When the function (the $y$ value) is negative or $0,$ we do have $x \leq 1.$  On the other hand, out of that, $y$ is positive for $x$ between the two roots with negative $x.$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

" If P and ¬Q for all x>1, then it should be true for x=2"

That will be a single confirmation.  That is not enough to prove anything. To prove something you have to show it is true for *ALL* $x > 1$.  Not just for *one* value of $x > 1$.

Suppose I wanted to prove $n^2$ is an even number for all $n \ge 7$.  So I try it with $n=8$ and $n^2 = 8^2 = 64$ is even.  That's not enough to prove it....  Or if I wanted to prove that everyone in New York is named Norman... and I find that one person in New York is named Norman....

But we *can* prove it for every $x > 1$.  If $x > 1$ then $x^2 = x*x > x*1 =x$ and $x^3 = x*x^2 > x*1 = x > 1$.  And $x > 1 \implies 7x > 7*1=7$.  So $x^3 + 7x -8 > 1 + 7 - 8 > 0$.

You were correct about the contrapositive.

$x > 1 \implies x^3 + 7x - 8 > 0$ so $x^3 + 7x -8 \le 0 \implies x \le 1$.